# GitHub: Create branch from an issue

Tags: github, github-for-mac

Is there a way to create a branch from an issue from Github's website?

[image]

Once I select an issue, is there a way to create a branch from the site and then clone it?  Or an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming across this question in October 2022, there now is a way to do that directly in Github!
This functionality is apparently in public beta right now and subject to change, according to the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/creating-a-branch-for-an-issue) about it.

To try this feature, just navigate to an issue and open it.
Then, on the panel on the right side of the page, you can find a clickable button to "Create a branch". See the attached screenshot for an example.

[image]

Comment: How can I create second branch for the same issue??

Answer (score 2):

No way.
But if you want to create a new branch from web interface use [official guide page](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository/).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: You can automate the creation of issue branches by installing [Create Issue Branch](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch#create-issue-branch) (FD: I'm the author of this App/Action)